# Merge statement issue - error unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Tags: oracle, sql-merge

Hi I am getting error while running the below merge statement in oracle db , can you please let me know how to fix the below error ?

--Query

```
MERGE INTO d_prod_fld dp USING
  (SELECT stg_prod_fld_id,
          prod_cd_id,
          country_name
   FROM stg_prod_fld_delta pd
   LEFT OUTER JOIN d_loc dl ON (dl.prod_cd_num=lpad(pd.prod_cd_id, 3, '0'))
   WHERE pd.efft_to > trunc(sysdate+1)
     AND pd.prod_cd_id IS NOT NULL ) stg
ON (dp.cd_id=stg.stg_prod_fld_id) 
WHEN matched THEN
UPDATE
SET dl.prod_country=stg.country_name;
```

- `d_prod_fld` - target dimension table ,
- `stg_prod_fld_delta` - stage table ,
- `d_loc` - look up table

basically when i tried to run the above query in sandbox it is running fine ,but when i tried to run in actual development environment it is showing the above error  -

Error starting at line : 1 in command -

> Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
>   30926. 00000 -  "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"
>   *Cause:    A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml
>              activity or a non-deterministic where clause.
>   *Action:   Remove any non-deterministic where clauses and reissue the dml.

Answer (score 0):

This means parallel DML's are happening in the source table stg_prod_fld_delta or lookup table d_loc which are modifying the results of the SELECT query.

You need to acquire a lock on stg_prod_fld_delta and d_loc using **select * from table where condition =value for update no wait** before running the MERGE statement .

Also issue COMMIT after the MERGE statement.

Please check the below

```
   SELECT *
   FROM stg_prod_fld_delta pd
   WHERE pd.efft_to > trunc(sysdate+1)
   AND pd.prod_cd_id IS NOT NULL 
   for update no wait;

   select * from d_loc dl
   for update no wait;

   MERGE INTO d_prod_fld dp USING
   (SELECT stg_prod_fld_id,
      prod_cd_id,
      country_name
      FROM stg_prod_fld_delta pd
      LEFT OUTER JOIN d_loc dl ON (dl.prod_cd_num=lpad(pd.prod_cd_id, 3, 
      '0'))
     WHERE pd.efft_to > trunc(sysdate+1)
      AND pd.prod_cd_id IS NOT NULL ) stg ON (dp.cd_id=stg.stg_prod_fld_id) 
      WHEN matched THEN
      UPDATE
      SET dl.prod_country=stg.country_name;

     COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation psaraj12 , can you please put in the query so that i will test

Comment: I have tried Psaraj12 it is again showing the same error , i really don't understand if run in sandbox it is running fine where as if i run in dev environment it is showing the same error ,  i tried adding distinct after select the query is running put updating double the records .. any solution ?

Comment: Hi rakesh ,what do you mean updating double the records,please give an example

Comment: Hi Raj correction - 17,413,741 rows merged. - the query merged - i messed up the database table  with this merge statement i need to rollback ? is this possible ? i have issued commit unforunately

Comment: You can rollback to an earlier state if archive log is enabled in development environment

Comment: Dear Raj how to check that any query to check  ?

Comment: it is a DBA activity, Please check with your DBA

Comment: i have tried using distinct the result expected is 614 but after running the update 1364 rows but when i do the select 614 only but why it is updating 1364 rows ?    MERGE INTO d_prod_fld dp USING
   (SELECT distinct stg_prod_fld_id,
      prod_cd_id,
      country_name
      FROM stg_prod_fld_delta pd
      LEFT OUTER JOIN d_loc dl ON (dl.prod_cd_num=lpad(pd.prod_cd_id, 3, 
      '0'))
     WHERE pd.efft_to > trunc(sysdate+1)
      AND pd.prod_cd_id IS NOT NULL ) stg ON (dp.cd_id=stg.stg_prod_fld_id) 
      WHEN matched THEN
      UPDATE
      SET dl.prod_country=stg.country_name;

Comment: that is because 614 rows in source table matches 1364 rows in target table